# 'Code Runner' extension shows "Could not find or load main class" when running Java programs inside a package/folder. (VScode)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

When I try to run my Java program through "Code Runner" extension while it is inside a package/folder, it shows error "Could not find or load main class".

But if I run same program through marked "Run | Debug" , the programs runs successfully. it also runs succesfully on code runner if the class is outside the folder.

Here are pictures to visualize my problem more clearly.

[This one is run through code runner when the classes are inside the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiVDs.png)

It doesn't work here

[This one is run through code runner when the classes are outside the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgfpz.png)

It works here

[This one is run through the run button over the main function, it runs the program through the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkKji.png)

It works here

the white and black lines are drawn to hide some personal information.

Is something wrong with 'Code Runner' extension? Btw, 'Code Runner' runs Python, C, C++ without any problem. even if they are inside a folder in these languages, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a test, I created the following directory structure:

```
Test
├── Test1.java
└── Test2
    └──Test2.java
```

As you described, the compilation runs normally in the first-level directory, but an error occurs in the second-level directory.

[image]

It's not entirely a matter of **Code Runner** extensions, there are also language specifications for the **Java** language itself.

As a test, you can run the program directly from the command line using the `javac` and `java` commands.

We can see that in the secondary directory, the compilation is successful, but the operation fails.

[image]

Use the **run** button on the code block to run successfully. We observed the command line code and found that it is not running the code in the secondary directory, and it specifies the classpath path.

[image]

Looking back, we return to the first level directory on the command line, run the `java` command again, and the operation is successful.

[image]

So we see that the command executed by the code runner is to simply run the javac and java commands directly in the current directory, so the operation fails.

[image]

Also as you said, languages like **python** don't have this problem. Because they don't have this language specification.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the java *packages* which are a means to organize sources,
actual a very useful feature considering easily dealing with hundreds of sources.

Java uses a folder tree = package hierarchy.
(Package names (directories) by convention are in small letters.)

- C:\Users\Me\JavaProject> javac foo/bar/Hello.java
- C:\Users\Me\JavaProject>

  - foo\

    - baz\

      - World.java

        ```
        package foo.baz;
        public class World {
            public static final WORLD = "World";
        }
        ```
    - bar\

      - Hello.java

        ```
        package foo.bar;
        import foo.baz.World;
        public class Hello {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello " + World.WORLD + "!");
            }
        }
        ```
      - Hello.class
- C:\Users\Me\JavaProject> java foo/bar/Hello

  Hello World!

The consequence of having packages means that you must compile and execute in the root directory. When packing the .class files in a .jar file (a zip format) it becomes easier, the directories are inside the jar file.

An IDE will help with all this.
A build infrastructure could be *maven* (or *gradle*). A maven project provides a conventional directory layout, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

custom classpath VSCode code runner & redhat java & gradle

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  "java": "gradlew build && java -cp \"$workspaceRoot/jvm/build/libs/api-full.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 $fullFileName"
}
```

change `jvm/build/libs/api-full.jar` with your dependencies jars relative to root project. You can add multiple jars looks like `$workspaceRoot/jvm/build/libs/api-full.jar;$workspaceRoot/jvm/build/libs/okio.jar;$workspaceRoot/jvm/build/libs/okhttp.jar`

when you got error `gradlew` command not found. Add terminal PATH to `.vscode/settings.json`

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PATH": "${workspaceFolder};${env:PATH}"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PATH": "${workspaceFolder}:${env:PATH}"
  }
```

close terminal and run the java file again.

My full working settings.json.

```
{
  "java.compile.nullAnalysis.mode": "disabled",
  "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
  "java.autobuild.enabled": true,
  "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19",
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-19",
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19"
    }
  ],
  "gradle.nestedProjects": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": "never",
    "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
  },
  "triggerTaskOnSave.on": false,
  "triggerTaskOnSave.restart": true,
  "triggerTaskOnSave.delay": 3000,
  "triggerTaskOnSave.showStatusBarToggle": false,
  "triggerTaskOnSave.showNotifications": false,
  "triggerTaskOnSave.showBusyIndicator": true,
  "triggerTaskOnSave.resultIndicator": "statusBar.background",
  "triggerTaskOnSave.failureColour": "#ff0000",
  "triggerTaskOnSave.successColour": "#00ff00",
  "triggerTaskOnSave.selectedTask": "boot-jar",
  "triggerTaskOnSave.tasks": {
    "build": [
      "**/src/!ModuleVersion.h",
      "**/src/**/*.java",
      "**/src/**/*.kt",
      "**/src/**/*.html",
      "**/src/**/*.css",
      "**/src/**/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {},
  "java.jdt.ls.androidSupport.enabled": "off",
  "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
  "java.import.generatesMetadataFilesAtProjectRoot": true,
  "java.import.exclusions": [
    "./.cache",
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/.metadata/**",
    "**/archetype-resources/**",
    "**/META-INF/maven/**"
  ],
  "java.maven.downloadSources": false,
  "java.edit.smartSemicolonDetection.enabled": true,
  "java.editor.reloadChangedSources": "auto",
  "boot-java.change-detection.on": false,
  "boot-java.live-information.automatic-connection.on": true,
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PATH": "${workspaceFolder};${workspaceFolder}\\bin;${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\.bin;${env:PATH}"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PATH": "${workspaceFolder}:${workspaceFolder}/bin:${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin:${env:PATH}"
  },
  "java.sharedIndexes.enabled": "off",
  "java.project.resourceFilters": [
    "node_modules",
    "\\.git",
    "\\.cache"
  ],
  "java.project.outputPath": "./build/redhat-java",
  "java.server.launchMode": "Standard",
  "code-runner.respectShebang": true,
  "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
  "code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
  "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
  "code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": false,
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "code-runner.executorMap": {
    "java": "gradlew build && java -cp \"$workspaceRoot/jvm/build/libs/api-full.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 $fullFileName"
  },
  "code-runner.executorMapByGlob": {
    "pom.xml": "cd $dir && mvn clean package",
    "**jvm/**/*java": "gradlew build && java -cp \"$workspaceRoot/jvm/build/libs/api-full.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 $fullFileName"
  }
}
```